# Sending two http resonses to client for a single httprequest

Tags: scala, http, playframework

Is there any way to send out two httpresponses for a single httprequest in play framework.
As as per the RFC of http we can send out two messages for a single request although as I am really novice in Play framework, can this be done.

If not what might be the best approach to solve this scenario

Comment: What is the use case? Why you want to send two responses at once?

Comment: not at once , need to send ok response as an handshake then followed with the actual response which is calculated after extensive mathematical operations

Comment: Use http chunked response.

Comment: Look at http chunked response documentation https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaStream#Chunked-responses

Comment: have used chunked response like-                                                                    
 val streamContent = Source.fromFuture(getFutureMessage(10.seconds))              then using Ok.chunked(streamContent) but could not see two response on the browser in the developer tool's network tab

Comment: I mean in a single response (long lived connection) you will get two messages

Comment: yes pamu, I get it but it will not fetch any purpose for my cause, would like something sort of behaviour like tcp where server can respond back to client that this is the next response that you would like. chunked will be some sort of streaming where a large response is broken down to be sent

Comment: Maybe you want to check `Expect: 100-continue` header spec? With this header you'll get an interim `100 Continue` response, -- sometimes -- but all other cases of 2 responses for one request would be HTTP response splitting attack, **forbidden**.

Comment: Maybe you could use a WebSocket to keep the connection open between the client and backend. that way you can send as many "responses" as you want to the client.
Docs: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaWebSockets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Little note**: This solution does not use `chucnked`, and use the `xmlHttp` request instead. And also, there is no magic: two requests and two responses. So if you have a constraint on the front-end framework; this might not be the best answer.

You also commented this:

> not at once , need to send ok response as an handshake then followed with the actual response which is calculated after extensive mathematical operations

So, if you don't have any constraints on your front-end framework; I would simply use the advantage of Javascript to send the second request, in the background, and get the second response back. Here how I would do it:

Update my `views` file to take a parameter, `handShake` of type `Boolean`. So when to user goes the page for the first time, the controller method response is `false`. After the first hand shake, the controller method, sends `true` with `Ok` response to the user. Only then when it is `true` **the app itself** sends another request, as an `xmlhttp` request via the javascript code, to the controller, and then the corresponding controller method, calculates what it needs to calculate and sends the response back.

This way you send two requests, and get back two responses, but you don't reload the whole page for the second request.